# How to monitor access of database in android?

Tags: android, database

I want to develop an Android application which will be used to monitor SQLite database Access

Is there any events generated when any application opens the database? And how should I monitor the actions performed by the other application on the SQLite Database?

Comment: Read the documentation, learn, try something, then post your doubts here. It will be much more productive for you and for everyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There're not API, or callback, or event, or broadcast to monitor other apps database access.

The database itself is just a file in the app data folder, which by definition, no other apps 
have access to it.